# pyttsx setup on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyttsx

I am wondering if I can use pyttsx with PyCharm. I have installed it via terminal and it works in the terminal python shell. I have tried, though Im not sure this is the correct way, but going into PyCharm/Preferences and gone to project interpreter, clicked + and searched for pyttsx, then downloaded and tried, with no luck. I need this to work the same as terminal in PyCharm. If you can tell me how to do this in IDLE, that would be ok to, but not ideal. I am using the latest IDLE (3.6.4) and PyCharm build #PC-153.4301.16. I am looking for this to work with python. I have looked around the internet and have found nothing. Here is a snippet of what I am trying to do: `import pyttsx
 engine = pyttsx.init()
 engine.say('Good morning.')
 engine.runAndWait()`
I have looked on other stack overflow pages, none of witch have helped. I have also looked on the PyCharm website.

Answer (score 0):

So PyCharm is fun. But essentially you don’t need to do anything. It should work “out of the box”. If you’re experiencing issues, post the error output so we can better assist you!

In general though pycharm will try and use a venv so make sure that you’re selecting your system interpreter. If it’s installed in your system then you don’t need to get it “through” pycharm because it’s just doing the same thing as pip (for the most part).

That said, because you’re using python 3+ you need to

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

Then

```
import pyttsx3
```

pyttsx was not made for python 3+ and has some serious incompatibilities with it. Whereas pyttsx3 is the updated version that was made for python 3+.